# iPhone stops running Javascript with exec()

Tags: javascript, regex, iphone

I've narrowed the problem down to this code...

```
var regex = /(?<=,')(.*)(?=')/;
var match = regex.exec(source);
```

... which is breaking my website on an iPhone (causing Javascript to stop working). My javascript is working fine in other browsers (Mac desktop, Android phone).

`source` is an onclick attribute that I'm pulling from an HTML element.

```
var allKeywords = document.getElementsByClassName("checkmark");
var source = allKeywords[i].onclick;
```

resulting in...

```
function onclick(event) {
keywordNegative('cat_gtr','cat_gtr');return false;
}
```

I'm trying to grab the second argument ("cat_gtr"). What's the better way to get it? By the way I have to use onclick inline because I'm entering the parameters using PHP.

Comment: Match normally instead of using negative lookbehind, then extract the capture group in the middle

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem and solution.